# Is it possible to send video link from my web site to Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, notifications

I have a website with videos. I wish to send the video or video link when I add a new video from my website administrator panel to my friends who use iphone. What steps I need to do?
Should my friends require to download any app from itune? Or we need another app specific for this facility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need iApp and [APNS](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) for notifications. So you can alert user and send inApp data...

Comment: thanks. So they need to install app in their iPhone. But, is it possible to view the videos in the iphone itself or the link open safari browser ?

Comment: I have tried the code in the URL http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services
and it worked for me.

Here is the payload Json.

{
    "aps": { 
        "alert" : "You got a new message!" ,
        "badge" : 5, 
        "sound" : "beep.wav"},
     "acme1" : "bar", 
     "acme2" : 42
}

But I wish to pass a URL to video(eg: http://www.mysite.com/viewvideo.php?id=56) in the alert message. is it possible?

Comment: It's better to pass custom properties directly to your application and inform user with some text and badge.